# How would I start to solve this?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I need to calculate the derivative of $F(x)=\int_{f(x)}^{f^2(x)}f^3(t)dt$.
Usually for a derivative of an integral I would plug the upper bound and lower bounds into $f(t)$ then multiply each by their respective derivatives, but I'm not sure how substituting in would work here?

Answer (score 3):

Write

$$F(x) = \int_{a}^{f^{2}(x)}f^{3}(t)dt-\int_{a}^{f(x)} f^{3}(t)dt.$$

Define $H(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f^{3}(t)dt$ and $G(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f^{3}(t)dt.$ Then

$$F(x) = H(f^{2}(x)) - G(f(x))$$

and

$$F^{\prime}(x)= H^{\prime}(f^{2}(x)) 2f(x)f^{\prime}(x) - G^{\prime}(f(x))f^{\prime}(x).$$

Calculate $H^{\prime}(x)$ and $G^{\prime}(x)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus as usual.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\begin{align}F'(x) &= \dfrac{d}{dx} \int_{f(x)}^{f^2(x)}f^3(t) \, dt \\ &= \frac{d}{dx} \left[\int_0^{f^2(x)} f^3(t) \, dt - \int_0^{f(x)} f^3(t) \, dt \right] \\ &= f^3(f^2 (x))(2f(x)f'(x))-f^3(f(x))(f'(x)).
\end{align}
$$